# Is there a GNU Make-type program for the D programming language?

Tags: makefile, d

Or on Windows I guess I could use a batch script?

Comment: Why would the language D need a special dependency make program?

Comment: It's because I'm using DMD, not GDC. Or would GNU Make from MinGW work with that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make is language agnostic: it works equally well (or bad depending on your point of view) with any programming language.

Comment: To still clarify: make is language/compiler/toolchain/whatever independent. You have to explicitly tell it how to call the compiler, which flags to use, etc. Thus, it works with any compiler made by anyone anywhere for any language.

Comment: This is almost correct. `make` has some assumptions built into it. For example, it assumes that every rule produces a single file. Its' support for tools that produces more then one target from a single source with a single command (such as yacc), is awkward at best. Also GNU make has some automatic rules for some languages, but not others.

Comment: I think the question may stem from the fact that GNU make comes with a whole bunch of predefined rules; many are for C or C++, and I don't think there are any for D.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you check the [rdmd](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/rdmd.html) utility, which is part of the standard dmd distribution. rdmd takes your main module and infers all transitive dependencies from it.

Answer (score 0):

The Digital Mars D compiler (which you can find [here](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/dmd-windows.html)) should have a `make` program that does what you need, in the `DMD2\Windows\Bin` folder.

If it doesn't, take a look at the C compiler -- I'm sure that at least one of them has one that works with DMD.